# What are some Game Development Publications that accept outside articles

Tags: marketing, business, publishing, articles

What Are some Game Development publications (electronic or otherwise) that aren't so large that there is no chance to potentially get included in the publication after a few well-written articles sent their way.

Looking for publications geared towards developers, not gamers, and can be any aspect of the game process, design, development, business, etc.

Comment: What are some game development publications that actually have an editorial staff supporting only "inside" articles? (Heck, what publications period can support such a thing these days?)

Answer (score 4):

[Game Developer](http://www.gdmag.com/write/) magazine?

Comment: I wrote an article for them, and can recommend it.. it was a very interesting experience, in a positive way.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Game Developer](http://www.gdmag.com/write/) and [Gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/) there is [Develop](http://www.develop-online.net/) which has a more EU tilt and the more recently launched [Gamesauce](http://gamesauce.org/news/) which is a small growing publication and probably the most interested in unsolicited articles.

Answer (score 4):

We're always interested in contributions from industry professionals. Feel free to contact me!

Best regards,

Vlad Micu

European Editor for Gamesauce Magazine

---

Answer (score 3):

[Gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/) might be an option.

I don't know if they are too big and they do not explictly request articles but their site covers some of the topics you list.

Their email address is at the bottom of their page.

Comment: They also have user blogs, and regularly feature excellent posts from them.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a publication, but you can always share articles you've written on gamedev.net

Answer (score 1):

Most publications accept submissions.  Look for a "submissions" or "contact us" link on their websites and make sure to follow their guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to software engineering and production, [Communications of the ACM](http://cacm.acm.org/) and [ACM Queue](http://queue.acm.org/) both seemed to cover game software and related content (AI, graphics, real-time systems) regularly when I was a subscriber.